# Shaking off error without using "on error resume next"

Tags: vba, web-scraping

If i run my code keeping the line "On error resume next" in it, it works fine but if i take out this line then it stops showing an error "object variable or with block variable not set". Why it happens and if i like to run my script without "on error resume next" then how can i do that? Thanks in advance to take a look into it.

```
Sub CandyCrush()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim Items As Object, Item As Object

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set Items = html.getElementsByClassName("left")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Item In Items
        x = x + 1
        Cells(x, 1) = Item.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
        Cells(x, 2) = Item.getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
    Next Item
End Sub
```

Elements for the class n tag:

```
<div class="left">
              <h1 itemprop="name">Candy Crush Saga</h1>
              <h2>By King</h2>
              <div class="editorial-badge">Essentials</div>
            </div>
```

Extended Portion:

```
Sub RealYP()
Const URL = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page=2"
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, topics As Object, topic As HTMLHtmlElement

With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("info")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each topic In topics
        x = x + 1
        If CBool(topic.getElementsByClassName("track-visit-website").lentgh) Then _
        Cells(x, 1) = topic.getElementsByClassName("track-visit-website")(0).href
    Next topic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically check to see if an element exists before attempting to access it and always define the parent worksheet of Cells.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    For Each Item In Items
        x = x + 1
        if cbool(Item.getElementsByTagName("h1").length) then _
            .Cells(x, 1) = Item.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
        if cbool(Item.getElementsByTagName("h2").length) then _
            .Cells(x, 2) = Item.getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
    Next Item
end with
```

If you run this and find that there is a row with empty cells in columns A and B then there was a div element (class="left") that did not contain an H1 and H2 element.

A .Length of zero means that there are none (one-based index). However, accessing the elements is a zero-based index so the first one (if one exists) is at `.getElementsByTagName("h2")(0)`.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!! It's totally foreign to me - the CBool stuff. Works perfect. Thanks sir, Jeeped for such a nice solution.

Comment: Btw, if I'm not impolite enough to ask that the extended portion containing another code with the same logic doesn't work, you might take a look into that in your spare time. Thanks.